# ethjsonrpc /python /bytes32 type argument assertion

Tags: transactions, json-rpc, bytes32

When I use the ethjsonrpc, some problem about `bytes32` type argument assertion occurs as the picture shows. I don't know where the problem lies and the correct way to assert the `bytes32` type argument using `call_with_transaction` in ethjsonrpc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

modify the command like this

```
"""c.call(c.eth_coinbase(),contract_addr,'set_a(bytes)',["0xd28fff4b2860a76e8f7b8bf334404eff3b2193d8a22b39cf1b77df777268388d"])"""
```

may help